# How to use InStrRev and Split functions together in Access VBA to split string before last occurrence of character?

Tags: string, vba

I am trying to find the last occurrence of a "\" in a string (it's a file path) and split the string to include everything up to and including the "\" so only the filename is left out. For example I have the path as "C:\Users\exampleUser\examplefile.txt" and I want it just to return "C:\Users\exampleUser\". I have found ways to do this on other languages but not VBA.

EDIT: I don't want this to be hardcoded by the way. I am using filesystem objects to loop through all subfolders and perform certain commands on specific files of a given name and path, so I don't know what the filepath will be through each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, you could just try `Left` and `InStrRev`:

```
Function GetDirectoryName(ByVal strFile As String, ByVal strDelimiter As String) As String
    GetDirectoryName = Left(strFile, InStrRev(strFile, "\", -1))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using the `FileSystemObject`, the easiest way is to use the built in [GetParentFolderName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22dyy47c(v=vs.84).aspx) method to do this:

```
Private Sub Example()

    Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim path As String

    Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    path = fso.GetParentFolderName("C:\Users\exampleUser\examplefile.txt")
    Debug.Print path

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSTRREV` and `MID` or `RIGHT` to do this. `InStrRev("c:\testpath\testfile.txt","\")`  or `Split(strInput, "\")(UBound(Split(strInput, "\")))`